# VB.NET holding a big vector of structure in memory

Tags: vb.net, windows, out-of-memory

I need to load a huge dataset keep it in a vector.
I have been able to make it so that the memory is kept right under the limit of around 1.2 gb that seems to be allowed for applications.

But then I tried to serialize the vector, and that is when VB.NET finally gave up giving me an out of memory exception.

I have tried just everything, I can not reduce the size of the dataset. 
In fact it is already really reduced. 
Changing the internals of my application is not an option.

Is there any way to allow my application to use more than 1.2 gb (or whatever seems to be this magic limit)?

I tried the same in VB6, and the limit was also 1.2 gb.

Answer (score 0):

This was what I Googled:

```
.net memory limit for application
```

These are the first 4 results on Google:

[Hitting a memory limit slows down the .Net application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767747/hitting-a-memory-limit-slows-down-the-net-application)

[.Net Memory limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587007/net-memory-limit)

[Is there a memory limit for a single .NET process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200348/is-there-a-memory-limit-for-a-single-net-process)

[Memory limitations in a 64-bit .Net application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107322/memory-limitations-in-a-64-bit-net-application)